# How do I turn off '*' in multi-line comments in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When coding with Eclipse, how do you turn off the "*" comments that come up when you start a multi-line comment?

Instead of seeing this,

```
/**
* Here is a comment
* some more 
*/
```

Can I get this?

```
/**
  Here is a comment
  some more
*/
```

If you are wondering the "/**" is because I use doxygen.

Comment: For the record, Doxygen strips the *'s, so it really doesn't matter one way or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg26720.html), you can only do that (meaning "disabling the leading asterisks") by going to

```
 Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates
```

So for example, if you modify the template for comments of a field into:

```
/**

 */
```

It will come that way (without any asterisk in the middle) when you will comment a Field.

However, it does go against the [**Sun convention** for Java comment formatting](https://web.archive.org/web/20091004164147/http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/index.html) up to jdk1.3 (update: [current oracle link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)) (as seen [also here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626135530/http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc4.html#16838))...
However, as noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641748/how-do-i-turn-off-in-multi-line-comments-in-eclipse/1641933#comment56743173_1641933) by [Amedee Van Gasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766786/amedee-van-gasse):

> Starting with Javadoc 1.4, [the leading asterisks are optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#leadingasterisks).

---

An even simpler way (if you only need to do that for certain comments of your codes, while keeping the other one with the standard style) is, when a multi-line comment appear like this one:

```
/**
 *
 */
```

, you can first remove the one leading asterisk, the enter your comments.
You will see no other leading asterisks are showing up at the beginning of each new line of comments.

```
 /**

  */

 /**
    My first line of comment
    My second line of comment
    My third line of comment
  */
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried that and unfortunately, it doesn't work. But, on a related note, the file I'm editing is a .c file. 

For everyone's information, even without the above hint, if I try to edit a java file, it does NOT give me the leading asterisk.

But, I need the feature for a C file !!!

Comment: I've been hunting for a while now. Since I can't seem to find anything better, I'm going with your second method. (I'll mark this as answered)

Comment: "However, it does go against the Sun convention for Java comment formatting (as seen also here)..." is not correct. It says: "Starting with Javadoc 1.4, the leading asterisks are optional."

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for your feedback. I have restored those old java.sun.com links, and updated the answer to include your comment.

Comment: To give my previous comment some content: our Java files start with a copyright header, with leading asterisks. The same text is in a MarkDown file, with 4 leading spaces, to make it monospaced. By changing the copyright header from asterisk-prefixed to 4-space-prefixed, I can use the MarkDown file in the CheckStyle config to check that the files have the appropriate copyright header.

Answer (score 0):

With eclipse 4.2.1 I used the formatter off / on feature, be sure to not have the formatter on tag on the same line as the comments tag other wise the stars nightmare will be back.

```
// @formatter:off
/*
Eclipse your * are messing up my comments big time and If I used you
more often I'd put a patch together to add back in the "Add Leading Star" option 
*/
// @formatter:on
```

The on/off features have to be turned "on" in Eclipse preferences: Java > Code Style > Formatter. Click on "Edit" button, "Off/On Tags", check off "Enable Off/On tags".

From

[How to turn off the Eclipse code formatter for certain sections of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code)

Also. I change the tags to //off //on for ease of use

A similar post is
[How to disable the automatic asterisk (inserting stars) in Eclipse when adding a multi-line comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233636/how-to-disable-the-automatic-asterisk-inserting-stars-in-eclipse-when-adding-a/17386783#17386783)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've moved to other IDEs right now, but will try out your answer if I get the time later.