# How to disable the automatic asterisk (inserting stars) in Eclipse when adding a multi-line comment?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

When adding a multi-line comment in Eclipse and format it(Ctrl+Shift+F), it automatically places an asterisk (*) at the beginning of each new line inside the comment block.

```
/*
 * this is my comment
 */
```

What is the reason of this behavior?

How can I disable it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641748/how-do-i-turn-off-in-multi-line-comments-in-eclipse see your answer

Comment: Please don't do that. That has been the standard way of writing block comments since the first days of the C programming language. Breaking conventions like this makes it harder for others (including automated tools) to read your code. So don't do it. Please?

Comment: @thkala I sometimes use star blocking for commenting my codes temporarily. After that when I want to uncomment it, I have trouble to remove extra stars.

Comment: @breceivemail: Try `Ctrl+/` in Eclipse. Or mark and `Ctrl+/` for multiple lines :-)

Comment: When a code with "//" code is committed, each commented line leads to a change in the file. This is not desired and should be solved with block comments. The added asterisk, however, also leads to a change at each disalbed line.

Comment: Traditional block comments suck. Badly. You have to manually un-asterisk them, they're ugly, they provide no useful function, and they add a bunch of unnecessary spaces. Everyone should break away from the "standard way" and do what's sensible instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Eclipse 4.2 and later, the solution is: *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter ->*

**$profileName** *-> Edit... (*) -> comments ->* **un-check** *[ ] Enable block comment formatting*.

Note that the author asked for block comments (`/*`) and not for Javadoc comments (`/**`).

To supress leading * for Javadoc comments **un-check** *[ ] Enable Javadoc comment formatting*

---

(*) If $profileName -> Edit... doesn't work, create a new template using "New...".

[image: See image highlighted in yello]

Answer (score 5):

It's the standard [javadoc format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).  Formatting options in eclipse are in right click your project->properties->Java Code Style->Formatter->Edit->Comments tab, but I don't see an option to disable this particular behavior.

Comment: It's actually [optional for javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#leadingasterisks). But +1 since I don't see a way to change this behavior either, contrary to what @Mick said.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools/Options/Editor/Formatting`  and select `Language = Java`, `Category = Comments` and uncheck `Add Leading Star`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window/Preferences/Code Style/Formatter`.
In Active Profile instead of **Eclipse[Built-in]** create a new profile and click edit.

Click on the "**`Comments`**" dropdown and uncheck:

1. Enable Javadoc comment formatting.
2. Enable block comment formatting.
3. Enable line comment formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that.

That has been the standard way of writing block comments since the first days of the C programming language. Breaking conventions like this makes it harder for others (including automated tools) to read your code.

If you need to quickly comment/uncomment Java code, you can try the `Ctrl+/` shortcut. It will use single-line comments (`//`) to comment-out the current line, or any number of marked lines of code.

Comment: Personally I would like to see them go away. They are [optional for javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#leadingasterisks) and git in the way when pasting code/markdown. All modern editors show the text in a different color also so we don't need the asterisk to offset it.

Comment: The reason I want them gone is to quickly *uncomment* large sections of code.  I don't want to have to remove each leading star.  It is much *much* faster to remove the leading and trailing notations.

Comment: Boooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

With eclipse 4.2.1 I used the formatter off / on feature, be sure to not have the formatter on tag on the same line as the comments tag other wise the stars nightmare will be back.

```
// @formatter:off
/*
Eclipse your * are messing up my comments big time and If I used you
more often I'd put a patch together to add back in the "Add Leading Star" option 
*/
// @formatter:on
```

The on/off features have to be turned "on" in Eclipse preferences: Java > Code Style > Formatter. Click on "Edit" button, "Off/On Tags", check off "Enable Off/On tags".

From

[How to turn off the Eclipse code formatter for certain sections of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code)

Also. I change the tags to //off //on for ease of use

A similar post is
[How do I turn off '*' in multi-line comments in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641748/how-do-i-turn-off-in-multi-line-comments-in-eclipse)